# Synchronize Json data from server responce

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asynchronous

I have two async responces from Ios server:

```
serviceResponce1 = function(response, request){
   result1 = Jquery.parseJson(request);
}

serviceResponce2 = function(response, request){
   result2 = Jquery.parseJson(request);
}
```

Than I need filter these two results:

```
filterArray = result1.filter(function(item){
   return result2.indexOf(item.Id) !== -1;
}
```

but they coming `asynchronous` and filter doesn't works. (when I hard code data, it works) How to synchronize them?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve that is to make the second request inside the handler of the first request and then handle the response:

```
request1(function(res1) { 
 request2(function(res2) { 
  filter(res1, res2); 
 }) 
});
```

The second way is to use deferred object, if you using jQuery (latest versions) then you can use:

`$.when(request1, request2).done(filter)`

Comment: First one was helpful for me. Thanks!